# Check if n elements contains data attribute set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website where there are five checkboxes, a div that contains another divs which each div contains five input hidden that have a value `1` or `empty`. That value comes from DB.

That's an example to represent the div container with the divs:

```
<input checkbox value="a">
<input checkbox value="b">
<input checkbox value="c">
<input checkbox value="d">
<input checkbox value="e">
<div class="container">
    <div class="content" data-name="combine">
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="a" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="b" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="c" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="d" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="e" />
    </div>

    <div class="content" data-name="combine">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" data-name="a" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="b" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="c" />
        <input type="hidden" value="1" data-name="d" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" data-name="e" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In the `javascript` code i have this snippet:

```
if(elementLength > 0) {

    $("[data-name='combine'] div.tagsProds").each(function() {

        var element = $(this);

        $.each(enabledChecks,function(i, v) {

            if(element.find("input[name='"+v+"']").val() == "") {
                element.append("<div class='blocked'></div>");
                element.unbind("click");
                element.addClass("js_noSortable");
            }

        });

    });

}
```

The `javascript` first checks if the `div.container` has childs and if it has childs the code iterates each child. On each child i iterate the five each checkbox (`enabledChecks`) and i see if the input hidden are empty. What i need if that if the five input are empty then append the `div.blocked'.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you're trying to accomplish here. For each div, you want to take some action if any of the child inputs do not have a value?

Comment: @nrabinowitz I edited my question. Yes, i need to check in every div if the five inputs not containst a value to append another div.

Comment: Try using .after instead of .append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i don't have enough reputation to write a comment i write an answer.

First, i think that your answer is quite interesting if you're looking to find a way using a `jQuery` function, but as i don't know any function to do this i think that you can create an `array()` and when you check if the input has empty value push it to the array, when the loop finishes you check the `length` of the `array()` and if it matches with the number of your checkboxes then append the `.blocked`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to find divs matching some selector that have no child `input` elements with non-empty values. The `.filter` method seems like a good fit here:

```
$("[data-name='"+name+"'] div.tagsProds")
    .filter(function() {
        // assert that at least one child input has a value
        var $inputsWithValue = $(this).find("input[name='avail_" + v + "'][value!='']");
        return $inputsWithValue.length === 0;
    })
    .each(function() {
        // now act on those value-less divs
        $(this)
            .append("<div class='blocked'></div>")
            .addClass("js_noSortable")
            .unbind("click");
    });
```

Another selector-only option might look like:

```
$("[data-name='"+name+"'] div.tagsProds:not(:has(input[name='avail_" + v + "'][value!='']))")
    .each(function() {
        // now act on those value-less divs
        $(this)
            .append("<div class='blocked'></div>")
            .addClass("js_noSortable")
            .unbind("click");
    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/vrx2wk8g/

Note that the examples above follow the selectors in your sample code, but won't work against your sample markup.

Comment: All the child divs have the five input and the value comes from DB. For example, if the first child div has the five inputs empty append the `div.blocked`, but if the child div has only an input with a value then it's not necessary to append the `div.blocked'

Comment: If all inputs are empty, append `div.blocked`. Otherwise, do nothing. Is that right? That's what the code above does.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the answer, i wil check it to see if it works :)